Make attendees the Organizer of the event in Google meet using Calender API
I want to make one of the attendee as the organizer of the event. By organizer I mean the one who can permit someone to enter the meeting. The organizer is having a an email with different sub-domain. How can I do it ?

I tried adding these properties in the event object but it didn't work.
 anyoneCanAddSelf: false, visibility: 'private', organizer: { emailAddress: { address: externalId ?? mentor.email }, self: true, },

Please share all the codes as code blocks not as image so we can easily copy your code.
